# Install bootlaoder on a raw image created using dd tool

Tags: linux, virtualbox, images, bootloader, dd

Actually, I want to create an image of my Linux running computer where I can only SSH, can't access physically. For that, I have created a raw image of it using `dd`. The command I used to create the image is `dd if=/dev/xvda bs=1M of=image.img`. Now, I want to install bootloader or whatever is required on `image.img` so that a bootable USB disk can be created using it. Or, the image can be converted into VDI, VMDK or whatever image format is supported by VirtualBox.

Comment: Why don't you mount the image, mount `proc`, `sys`, and `dev`, and chroot to it to install the boot loader?

Comment: @JuliePelletier doesn't a bootloader need physical access to the block device - something chroot will thwart ?

Comment: (Comment because its only a partial solution) - You can make a file appear as a device by mapping it to a Loopback device - for example losetup loop2 /path/to/file - then run kpartx /dev/loop0 to create /dev/loop2p0 and /dev/loop2p1

Comment: @davidgo:  not necessarily but if it fails, he could also use `rdev`.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I don't have physical access to the server. How can I install bootloader using chroot?

Comment: @davidgo I have given a bunch of random tries like this found in the Internet. Could you please put your suggestions together?

Comment: @AshishBista:  Are you sure you can run VirtualBox on that machine?  In any case, the image produced already has a boot sector, you just need to change the kernel's root device default with a tool like `rdev`, but it could even be done with a hex editor.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I don't want to run VirtualBox on that machine. I meant if could run a VirtualBox machine on my local computer using that image is fine. Let me try `rdev`. I'm little bit scared of using a hex editor. But, thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Is the xvda bootable? If yes, just use dd to write the image into a USB disk.(dd if = the_path_of_your_image of = the_path_of_the_USB_disk)
Please note that the partition table will be copied too. So if the size of the USB disk is large than the xvda, you may need to expand the partition and then expand the file system.